# Android Hello World app crashes: IllegalArgumentException from Surface.lockCanvasNative

Tags: android, exception

I am trying to run the simplest [Hello World example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) app and looks like I can crash it even all it does is showing a TextView.

Steps to reproduce: Launch it in the emulator (1.5). Open the app - it shows the text view, then lock the phone by pressing "end call" button. Unlock by pressing "menu", then press "back". App crashes with "The process android.process.acore has stopped unexpectedly..." and Force Close button. It does not happen all the time, but I am able to reproduce it every time after wiping the user data at least.

I wonder if default Hello World is missing a detail which was considered too advanced for a hello world... Such problems with a basic example does not look very encouraging =)

Any idea what detail is missing and how to avoid this crash?

Stack (I've truncated timestamps):

```
37.478: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(576): wakeWhenReadyLocked(82)
37.481: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(576): handleWakeWhenReady(82)
37.481: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(576): pokeWakelock(5000)
39.110: DEBUG/KeyguardViewMediator(576): pokeWakelock(5000)
39.140: WARN/InputManagerService(576): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@436e3fc0
40.990: ERROR/IMemory(679): binder=0x238aa8 transaction failed fd=-2147483647, size=0, err=-2147483646 (Unknown error: 2147483646)
40.990: ERROR/IMemory(679): cannot dup fd=-2147483647, size=0, err=-2147483646 (Bad file number)
40.990: ERROR/IMemory(679): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0x238aa8), size=0, fd=-1 (Bad file number)
40.990: ERROR/Surface(679): Couldn't map Surface's heap (binder=0x238aa8, heap=0x238b00)
40.990: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(679): Shutting down VM
40.990: WARN/dalvikvm(679): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
40.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(679): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
40.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(679): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
40.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(679):     at android.view.Surface.lockCanvasNative(Native Method)
40.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(679):     at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:196)
40.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(679):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1175)
40.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(679):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1030)
40.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(679):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1482)
40.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(679):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
40.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(679):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
40.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
40.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(679):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
40.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(679):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
40.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(679):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
40.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(679):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
40.990: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(679):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
41.000: INFO/Process(576): Sending signal. PID: 679 SIG: 3
41.000: INFO/dalvikvm(679): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
41.030: ERROR/ActivityThread(576): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
41.030: ERROR/Checkin(576): Error reporting crash: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://android.server.checkin/crashes
41.070: INFO/dalvikvm(679): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
50.940: WARN/ActivityManager(576): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
50.980: WARN/ActivityManager(576): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{4366ac40 {com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher.Launcher}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds to me more like something wrong with your emulator. Why dont you delete your emulator and create a new one and try again with a fresh project.

Hope that will help you. BTW why are you using emulator on 1.5?? Start to build applications for min 2.1.

Good luck.

Comment: Hm-m-m... The error is not reproducible in 2.1 emulator with project target set to 2.1 or 1.5. But it is still appears (about once in two attempts) in newly created 1.5 emulator (when target is 1.5)... Must be some quirk of Android 1.5 then. Thanks!